# make changes to linux os

Tags: linux-device-driver

I Build Linux kernel for my embedded board.

I want to customize the features of my board.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which board do you use?

Comment: *"I want to customize the features of my board. They told me to edit the **device tree** file."* -- *"They"* may have given you incorrect/bad advice.. The Device Tree only describes the board/hardware that the kernel must run on and manage. Linux kernel *"features"* are *"customized"* using the kernel configuration methods, e.g. `make menuconfig`. The DT does not *"customize"* any *"Linux OS features"*.

Answer (score 0):

Create the following tree in your layer meta-custom:

```
recipes-kernel/
└── linux
    ├── linux-at91
    │   ├── 0001-my-custom-dt.patch
    └── linux-at91_%.bbappend
```

In `linux-at91_%.bbappend`, put

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://0001-my-custom-dt.patch"
```

To generate `0001-my-custom-dt.patch`, you can use the following steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91.git
cd linux-at91/
quilt new 0001-my-custom-dt.patch
quilt add arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d27_som1_ek.dts 
vim arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d27_som1_ek.dts

# modify DT

quilt refresh
```

You should obtain something like:

```
Index: linux-at91/arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d27_som1_ek.dts
===================================================================
--- linux-at91.orig/arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d27_som1_ek.dts
+++ linux-at91/arch/arm/boot/dts/at91-sama5d27_som1_ek.dts
@@ -538,7 +538,7 @@
        compatible = "gpio-leds";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_led_gpio_default>;
-       status = "okay"; /* Conflict with pwm0. */
+       status = "disabled"; /* Conflict with pwm0. */

        red {
            label = "red";
```

Finally copy patch in `recipes-kernel/linux/linux-at91` and relaunch Yocto build.

---

Note:
you could also create an entire custom device-tree by using [KERNEL_DEVICETREE](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-KERNEL_DEVICETREE) bitbake variable.

Comment: Hello Nayfe. Thank you for your support. But here you said to me : To generate `0001-my-custom-dt.patch` , you can use the following steps: `git clone https://github.com/linux4sam/linux-at91.git` . I must clone again Linux-at91 under the tree i made ? because i have cloned it before when i build the Linux image.

Comment: Generally I use kernel source in `<build>/tmp/work-shared/<machine>/kernel-source/` folder, or `devtool modify virtual/kernel` as described [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#using-devtool-to-patch-the-kernel)

Comment: You can just comment `# SRC_URI += "file://0001-my-custom-dt.patch"`

Comment: This doesn't answer the ambiguous question that was actually asked, which does not mention any specific feature to be modified or customized.  This seems to be an answer for some other post by Gonn.

Comment: @sawdust indeed there are several Gonn posts on same problem and I answered on latest post. It could be better to put it on this one `https://stackoverflow.com/q/57812953/6225741` or this one `https://stackoverflow.com/q/57578148/6225741` or edit the question. Anyway, I helped him.