# I can't manipulate my general purpose I/O

Tags: embedded-linux, device, gpio

I am using embedded Board.I am also using LIBGPIOD library to manipulate GPIOS configurations of the board. First, I can list all the lines of specified gpiochips, their names, consumers, direction, active state with `gpioinfo` command, and this shows me :

```
gpiochip0 - 128 lines:
        line   0:        "PA0"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   1:        "PA1"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   2:        "PA2"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   3:        "PA3"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   4:        "PA4"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   5:        "PA5"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   6:        "PA6"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   7:        "PA7"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   8:        "PA8"       unused   input  active-high 
        line   9:        "PA9"       unused   input  active-high 
        line  10:       "PA10"        "red"  output  active-high [used]
        line  11:       "PA11"       unused   input  active-high 
...
```

For my work, I want to let "PA10" GPIO PIN for personal use, this pin referres to RED Led. But whatever command dedicated to manipulate "PA10" GPIO PIN, exemple:

`gpioset --mode=wait gpiofind "PA10"=1`

it shows me :

> error setting the GPIO line values

I Think that is beacause it's shown as `[USED]` in front of it's line.

Is there a way to make it **UNUSED** ? To make it free so i can manipulate it ?

Comment: I'd start investigating if the gpio can be driven by echoing values into the proper sys/ entry on the shell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YOCTO : Modify Linux OS features by editing it's device tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838460/yocto-modify-linux-os-features-by-editing-its-device-tree)

Comment: @Claudio, you are recommending legacy way, while using `libgpiod` tools is a modern way of achieving the things.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have the LED driver using that gpio.  Remove it from your device tree and you will have control of the pin again.