# YOCTO : How can I exclude drrivers that are reserving and handling my embedded board GPIO

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, embedded-linux, yocto

I am using SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK1 embedded board. I used **YOCTO** project to build Linux Operating System.

When I show up the list of GPIOs existing on my board, I see that some of them are **" USED "**. Searching the net I found that the reason they are used is that there are some drivers / modules are handling that GPIOs.

So I opened the Linux kernel **MENUCONFIG** and I UNABLED some features like *" GPIO BUTTONS "* , *" LED SUPPORT "* .. and I re-build the kernel.

But the same issue comes out : The GPIOs are still used.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place, you rather have to modify your device tree and disable whatever requestes those GPIOs.

Comment: Why is it supposed as wrong place ? The menuconfig is supposed as a place where you can select what you need as configurations for your kernel and unable what you don't need ? Why it is not taking in consideration what i have modified ?

Comment: Because it is the wrong place, simple as that. menuconfig tells the kernel what it shall *support*, the device tree tells the kernel what is *there*. So the correct approach is to tell the kernel that there is no LED. Disabling just the LED driver in the menuconfig has the meaning of "here are LEDs but I'm not gonna tell you how to use them." Don't blame me for your expectations about how the kernel works.

Comment: Thank you for your explication. It's a bit clear for me now

Comment: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57850793/6225741) I gave you in previous thread didn't work ?

Comment: @Nayfe Hello. It's working and thank you for this solution. But, in work, they do not want to patch the DT file or modify it. Unfortunatly,  they want to achieve the goal in another way.